# How to select children using the children() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, children

I can't understand how to use children() function in jQuery, I have this code:

```
jQuery('#nav li.over a.level-top').css({'padding-bottom': '26px'});
```

I want to replace `#nav li.over` with `var navLiOver = jQuery('#nav li.over');`

This doesn't work:

```
navLiOver.children('a.level-top').css({'padding-bottom': '26px'});
```

Can anybody explain to me how the `children()` function works?

HTML code:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="level-top over">
        <a class="level-top">Link1</a>
        <ul class="level0">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What's your markup structure? `children()` will only select direct descendants that match the selector, whereas your first selector will select all `a.level-top` elements that are anywhere within the `li.over` hierarchy...

Comment: As you can see here, your JavaScript code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/JPxPm/. The problem is with the CSS.

Comment: _"Can anybody explain to me how the children() function works?"_ - Well yes, [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/children/) explains it fairly clearly.

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent of `$('#nav li.over a.level-top')` is `navLiOver.find('a.level-top')`

For your `padding-bottom` code to have any effect, though, you need to make sure that the anchor has a display mode that allows padding, such as `block` or `inline-block`. This is true regardless of how you find the element.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Aq54p/)

Answer (score 2):

you can use find()

```
navLiOver.find('a.level-top');
```

> The .find() and .children() methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level down the DOM tree.

whereas find()

> Gets all  the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements

Comment: This also doesn't work :/

Comment: can you post you html ??

Answer (score 0):

The difference between

```
jQuery('#nav li.over a.level-top')
```

and

```
jQuery('#nav li.over').children('a.level-top')
```

is that the latter only selects the immediate children. For the behaviour you are expecting, use find() instead.

Comment: As I said find() function also doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

Your code work's just fine

```
navLiOver.children('a.level-top')
```

The thing that doesn't work is `.css({'padding-bottom': '26px'});`

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/AXNW9/)

the `a` tag is `inline` by default. You cannot apply top/bottom padding to an inline element

If you want some padding around your `<a>` you can do this

```
a { color: #fff; display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; padding: 0px 0px 26px 0px;}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/AXNW9/2/)

Comment: I know that, it worked perfectly when I wrote this > jQuery('#nav li.over a.level-top').css({'padding-bottom': '26px'});